# YouTube data api v3 - Browser based uploading

Tags: .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

With the old gdata api I could upload directly to YouTube using a form post without having to upload the file to the server and post it on.

This is easy in javascript, as shown here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

However, I'm acquiring my access token using the .Net client library and storing a refresh token in my DB so I can't use the javascript version.

Is this supported in api v3?  Struggling to find anything about it.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the question.  But you can use a refresh token stored in the Database with the .net client library.  and the client library works with Youtube API.

Comment: I mean in the old api you could request that you want to upload a file and the api would tell you where to upload it to so you could create <form> on your webpage that allowed the user to browse to a file and upload it to youtube.  I'm looking for similar functionality with the api v3.  There is sample code that allows you to upload a local file but not for a user to choose a file and upload it